# How to configure swap space after system installation?

Tags: debian, swap

I've installed Debian Wheezy; after installation completed, I realized that I forgot to set the swap memory. So now, how can I configure the swap space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create a partition or RAID array or logical volume... (or use an existing one) for swap
2. `mkswap` that partition
3. Run `blkid that-block-device`
4. Add an entry to /etc/fstab in the form `UUID=7321174b-e4d8-4d9d-b223-113a1b8e9c9f swap swap sw 0 0` (see step 3 for actual UUID)
5. `swapon -a` or reboot

Comment: You can also use a file instead of a partition. It's slower, but will get the job done if you don't have room for an additional partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't create a new partition or add new disks, you can increase your swap with the following :

```
swapfile=swapfile01
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/$swapfile bs=1024 count=$(( 2*1024*1024 ))
mkswap -L $swapfile /var/$swapfile
echo "/var/$swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
swapon /var/$swapfile
```

NB - this creates a 2GB swapfile.  Adjust count= to requirements.

Answer (score -3):

FYI. If you configure a swap space on an encrypted container, it will break! I strongly advise you to configure swap volume during the OS setup phase.

Comment: Edit: if you try to configure swap space on logical volume where the encrypted container resides outside of the logical volume, it will break.

Comment: I am using swapfiles on encrypted volumes for years without setting them up in setup phase and never ran into problems.

Comment: ..running Debian.