# How to increase swap partition size without reinstall?

Tags: debian, partition

Trying to hibernate failed because the [swap is too small](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/745199/530603). Debian wiki pages do in my view not clearly explain how to fix this. [2](https://wiki.debian.org/Swap) [3](https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation#Changing_or_moving_the_swap_partition)

- [`gparted`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124726/530603) allows to manage the [partitions](https://wiki.debian.org/Partition). But it does not allow to decrease the size of the boot, esp partition. This means the swap partition size cannot be increased. The partition would need to be unmounted, which worries me a bit.
- rootuser.com guides one to [boot from another medium than HD](https://www.rootusers.com/lvm-resize-how-to-decrease-an-lvm-partition/) such as USB to be able to configure the partitions. A [blog](https://blog.michael.franzl.name/2021/07/18/failed-to-suspend-system-system-resumed-again-no-space-left-on-device-how-to-increase-swap-by-taking-the-space-from-a-different-logical-volume/) refers to this procedure stating "Doing so is quite easy." But is it? I see others have failed to ultimately increase [swap size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612690/linux-increase-swap-partition-failed).
- others have described [How to configure swap space after system installation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48454/how-to-configure-swap-space-after-system-installation)

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLB512HAJQ-000L7              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: AC1BEA07-5209-41FE-AF1A-79C3D68B3FE4

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1050624  998215679 997165056 475.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 998215680 1000214527   1998848   976M Linux swap

$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.0M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  467G   95G  349G  22% /
tmpfs           7.7G   13M  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M   23M  489M   5% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G  216K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000

$ mount    # edited
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
```

Comment: 1. Consider the reason for hibernation, something not enable by default; if your only reason is "cuz I wanna" you better keep the working system as it is. 2. If you have a valid reason then consider using a swapfile instead of a swap partition with the required maximum size that must be at least = amount of RAM (a little more is preferable).

Comment: In general (actually, all the time), one cannot change a disk's partition size while ANY of the disk's partition in mounted. That's why you're instructed to "boot from another medium than HD".

Comment: @waltinator In general, you can change the size of all unmounted partitions. I needed to do this quite often. As long as partitions are not required to run the systems, unmount them and chance their sizes. You just can't shrink a partition before the mounted partition to increase the size of a partition after the mounted one (and vice versa). Here, the problem is that the partition to be shrinked can't be unmounted.

Comment: @Philippos would it be possible to unmount Device=/dev/nvme0n1p2 Type=Linux filesystem either by booting from a USB or in rescue mode?

Comment: I don't know what kind of rescue mode is implemented, but it will be possible when booting from USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This worked out**

1. Backup with CloneZilla
2. Prepare offline configuration of partitions
3. Configure partitions
4. Final swap setup
5. Check partitions
6. Test hibernation

*1. Backup with CloneZilla*

- Requires at least one usb drive, one of which must have enough space for the backup.
- optionally a second to install CloneZilla Live on
- I decided to follow the strategy of making CloneZilla available as an iso image on the disk with an entry to the grub boot menu, making it easy to backup stuff in future without relying on two usb's

1. [Gnome-disk-utility failed so I was led to use CloneZilla Live](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191439/unable-to-create-backup-image-with-gnome-disk-utility), the ISO, not zip
2. [CloneZilla Live example at the bottom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines/1025657#1025657), and see [original guide](https://clonezilla.org/livehd.php)
3. I'm running Debian Bullseye and it was necessary to solve the bug of a slightly prior version by [inserting `rmmod tpm` before the `menuentry`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines/1025657#comment2155973_1025657)
4. when I got to running the actual program it was a bit buggy but worked out somewhat like described in the [original guide](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image)

*2. Prepare offline configuration of partitions [(no mounted filesystem)](https://www.rootusers.com/lvm-resize-how-to-decrease-an-lvm-partition/)*

1. reboot
2. edit BIOs to prioritize (and what not) boot from usb
3. boot from usb with Debian bullseye install to enter rescue mode where filesystem is not in use.

*3. Configure partitions*

- I could not use [a procedure described by another Debian bullseye user](https://blog.michael.franzl.name/2021/07/18/failed-to-suspend-system-system-resumed-again-no-space-left-on-device-how-to-increase-swap-by-taking-the-space-from-a-different-logical-volume/), because [there were no logical volumes or volume groups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747473/why-lvm-vgchange-lvreduce-detect-no-logical-volume-group/747478#747478), only partitions, as also explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/119458/1688470)

1. I deactivated swap of current swap partion, went to `gparted` and removed it, so I did not [backup the existing small swap partion uuid, so I had to setup swap at the end](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/747478/530603)
2. follow [rootuser.com advice](https://www.rootusers.com/lvm-resize-how-to-decrease-an-lvm-partition/) to first check filesystem `e2fsck -fy /dev/partition-here`, shrink it to slightly less than intended `resize2fs /dev/partition-here desired-minus-~10-G`, then shrink partition, however, using `parted`, and then `resize2fs` to actually desired size, then `parted` to create the `linux-swap` from end of filesystem to [100%](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966394/how-do-i-create-a-swap-partition-using-parted).

- for `parted` commands:

  1. `select device` (it defaulted to the usb device that booted rescue mode)
  2. [`unit GiB`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/747478/530603) (as explained at [archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Parted) this unit corresponds to the unit of `resize2fs xxxG`)

3. quit `parted` and use [`mkswap /dev/swap-partion-name`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165073/1688470)

*4. Final swap setup*

1. reboot was buggy (I hit the keyboard a few times in the hope of causing some progress) and it eventually entered Gnome :-)
2. [`swapon /dev/swap-partition-name`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165073/1688470)
3. update:
4. [`fstab`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1352066/1688470) (remember `# Please run 'systemctl daemon-reload' after making changes here.`),
5. [`RESUME`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1126353/1688470),
6. and [initrd/initramfs](https://askubuntu.com/a/1352066/1688470)
7. free -m
8. cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness

*5. check filesystem, disk partition table, partitions, and block devices*

1. `e2fsck -fy /dev/filesystem-partition-name-here`
2. `mount`
3. `fdisk -l /dev/encompassing-partition-name-here`
4. `df -h`
5. `lsblk`

*6. Test hibernation*

1. `systemctl hibernate`
2. `sudo journalctl -r -u hibernate.target`
3. `sudo systemctl list-dependencies -a hibernate.target`
4. `sudo systemctl status systemd-hibernate`

Answer (score 0):

Simply booting [gparted live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) from an USB stick would have given you the opportunity to act on all the partitions.